# phpQuery - скрипт выдает белую страницу

Tags: php, phpquery

Я пытался повторить материал из видеоурока про `phpQuery`, сверил весь код с точностью до запятой, но у меня отображается только пустая страница в итоге.

Код вроде бы совсем простой, ошибок не нахожу

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    require 'phpQuery.php';

$url='https://privatbank.ua/ru/';
$file=file_get_contents($url);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
$tbl = $doc->find('#course-table-pb');

echo $tbl;
```

Не может ли такого быть, что я версию `phpQuery` взял какую-нибудь не такую?

Проверяется по ходу:
$file - непустое
$doc - непустое
$tbl - пусто

Comment: Для того что бы убедиться что `$file` не пустой сделай `print_r($file);`

Comment: видеоурок ваш устарел, на странице по ссылке нет элемента с `#course-table-pb`

Comment: вернее, ее нет изначально. Данные грузятся через ajax после загрузки страницы.

Comment: [отсюда](https://currency.privatbank.ua/ru/get-currencies/) грузятся курсы валют

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Про ajax я совсем не подумал.

Comment: оформил ответом. можете принять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

подытожу свои комментарии.
Вы загружаете страницу по указанной ссылке. Когда вы ее открываете в браузере там выполняется множество JS-кода, который в частности подгружает курсы валют. И в результате вы видите страницу такой, какой видите.

Когда вы эту же страницу загружаете через `file_get_contents()` вы получаете только исходный код страницы, JS скрипты никто не обрабатывает. Поэтому динамические данные не загружаются. Можете сохранить вывод `file_get_contents` в файл (или просмотреть исходный код страницы в браузере) и там вы не найдете элемента `#courses-table-pb`, который запрашиваете через `phpQuery`.

В инструментах разработчика в браузере вы можете наблюдать, что курсы валют запрашиваются по ссылке https://currency.privatbank.ua/ru/get-currencies

Дальше действуйте из ваших интересов. Если ваша задача - изучить `phpQuery`, то найдите другую страницу для практики. Если задача - получить курсы валют, то загрузите json-данные по ссылке выше, декодируйте их с помощью `json_decode` и используйте по своему усмотрению, а phpQuery для данной задачи не нужен.

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://currency.privatbank.ua/ru/get-currencies/");
$content = substr($content, 1, strlen($content)-2);

$data = json_decode($content);
$data = json_decode($data->content);

print_r($data->exchange->currency_pb);
```